# See through object in Blender game engine

Tags: game-engine, materials

[Solved]
I have modeled a plane and made a little "world" However, if I add a simple camera and play around with it, it will see through and will show textures lower than where it is.
So before I run the game:
[image: object mode]

However, if i run the game
[image: BGE running]

As you can see, it will see through the ground. any ways to fix this? I tried recalculating the normals, flipping the normals, and checked the normals, but it wouldn't work.

Comment: I guess this needs more info. Could you share a .blend showing the issue?

Comment: @user2859 I have fixed the issue. It looks like I need to add a texture instead on a blank uv map. Thanks you, however

Comment: @user3167683 instead of editing the question as **solved** please write your own answer as an answer and not as a comment.

Comment: @cegaton Thank you for your advice. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. I was using a uv map as the texture for the plane. However, if I change the render mode from multitexture to GLSL, and use an image as an texture, it will display the plane correctly. It looks like there was a problem with the plane is under where I am, so it will show "through" the plane.